# Adding a UINavigationBar to UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I had my app perfectly working on iPhone OS 2.2.1 but now I am trying to make it work on iPhone OS 3.0.

And my application crushes, apparently because of having a UINavigationController in UITabBarController.

I get the following error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
'Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'
```

And I have no idea why does it happen and how to fix it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a a UINavigationController in each tab is perfectly fine. The problem you are experiencing is tied, apparently, to a wrong use of delegates. However, without the involved source code it is difficult to tell you where the problem lies.